# calculate $P(X_1 = 2 | X_1 + X_2 = 5)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$ be an observed sample from a $Geo(\theta)$ distribution with pmf given by

$f(x) = (1-\theta)^x \theta, x = 0,1,2,3,\cdots$

$0$  otherwise

where $\theta \in (0, 1)$ is an unknown parameter

(a) With $n = 2$, calculate $P(X_1 = 2 | X_1 + X_2 = 5)$ \

Solution:

(a)

$P(X_1 = 2 | X_1 + X_2 = 5) = \frac{P(X_1 = 2 \cap X_1 + X_2 = 5)}{P(X_1 + X_2 = 5)} = \frac{P(X_1=2 \cap X_2 = 3)}{P(X_1 + X_2 = 5)} = \frac{P(X_1=2)P(X_2 = 3)}{P(X_1 + X_2 = 5)}$

$$= \frac{(1-\theta)^2\theta (1-\theta)^3 \theta}{\text{ not sure how to evaluate this}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(X_1 + X_2 = 5) &= \sum_{k=0}^5 P(X_1 = k, X_2 = 5-k) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^5 (1-\theta)^k\theta(1-\theta)^{5-k}\theta \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^5 (1-\theta)^5\theta^2 = 6(1-\theta)^5\theta^2 \,.
\end{align}